# How to view dash app in 'inline' or 'jupyterlab' mode when host parameter differs for kernel and notebook

Tags: docker, plotly-dash

I'm running jupyter/dash inside of a docker container and would like to use the `inline` and `jupyterlab` modes of `app.run_server` as per the [getting started notebook](https://github.com/plotly/jupyter-dash/blob/master/notebooks/getting_started.ipynb).

However, while I've exposed port 8050 to the host in docker, I have to use IP `0.0.0.0` instead of the default when launching the app:

[image]

When I do this, I can connect just fine from the host by launching a browser with the address `http://127.0.0.1:8050`:

[image]

However, when I use `inline` or `jupyterlab` modes, I see this:

[image]

My understanding of what is happening here is that the flask app is launching on `0.0.0.0:8050` in the kernel/container, and then jupyterlab is attempting to open a tab on that same IP, but it can't since the server is exposed as `127.0.0.1:8050` on the host.

How can I tell `run_server` to connect to a different IP within jupyter than the one that app was launched in?

### Attempt 1

This kind of works:

[image]

However, it outputs the "dash is running on ..." repeatedly and eventually produces an exception printed out as a warning. I get a similar result when using `inline`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack but it does seem to work:

Cell 1:

```
import threading

t = threading.Thread(target = lambda: app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='8050'))
t.start()
```

Cell 2:

```
%%html
<iframe src="http://127.0.0.1:8050/" width="100%" height="650"></iframe>
```

I got those width/height values come from the default arguments to `app.run_server`.

End result:

[image]

I'm still interested in a better answer if there's a cleaner way of doing this.